# Select different fields from pair of rows in same table

Tags: sql, sql-server

| user | phone | datetime | duration | status | task | callID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Alice | 123 | 2022-08-29 18:59 | 52 | 2 | 111 | 222 |
| Bob | 567 | 2022-08-28 17:43 | 31 | 5 | 333 | 222 |

One table with two kinds of call records, with different ID in "task". Related calls always have same ID in "callID". I want to get some fields from record with task=111 and others from task=333, for each that pair. Like that(pseudocode):

```sql
SELECT A.user, B.phone, A.datetime, A.duration, B.status, A.callID
FROM MyTable
WHERE A.datetime BETWEEN... AND B.user='Alice'
```

JOIN? MERGE? UNION? Temporary tables and custom procedure?

Comment: Please show sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1):

You may aggregate by the `callID` and then use conditional aggregation to pivot out the fields of interest.  For example, to report the phones you could try:

```sql
SELECT callID,
       MAX(CASE WHEN task = 111 THEN phone END) AS phone_111,
       MAX(CASE WHEN task = 333 THEN phone END) AS phone_333
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY callID;
```

You may select other fields per task as shown above.

Answer (score 1):

You can join on the same table using Aliases (as if they were different tables) and supply additional WHERE/ON clauses

```
SELECT A.user, B.phone, A.datetime, A.duration, B.status, A.callID
FROM MyTable A
JOIN MyTable B ON B.CallId = A.CallId AND B.TaskId = 333
WHERE A.datetime BETWEEN... AND B.user='Alice'
  AND A.TaskId = 222
```

Comment: Exactly that I want. Thanks :)